# Could not deduce template argument when testing C++ with google mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, macros, googlemock

my code uses Google mock to test the class **EventLogger**.

In first place the compilation fails because the compiler does not find the parameter of the template in a macro, it fails deducting the argument :

```
candidate: template<class T, class ... Args> auto Filler<traceType>::fill(Args&& ...)
[with T = T; Args = {Args ...}; Class1 traceType = (Class1)1u]
 WRAP_MOCKED_TEMPL_METHOD_1(fill, T);
                            ^
In definition of macro 'WRAP_MOCKED_TEMPL_METHOD_1'
     auto NAME(Args &&...args)\
          ^
Template argument deduction/substitution failed:
     WRAP_MOCKED_TEMPL_METHOD_1(fill, T);

Couldn't deduce template parameter 'T''
```

So I tried to explicitly add the parameter when calling the function (comment //V2 in the code) but then appears an other error message:
`filler.fill<Message>(buffer, data, getMessage());`

```
In member function
void EventLogger<traceType>::write(const buffer&, const Message&):
Error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
    `filler.fill<Message>(buffer, data, streamInd);`
                        ^
```

**### Code ###**
Here is my code.

**Class tested**

```
template <Class1 traceType>
class EventLogger
{
public:
    template <typename Message>
    void write(const c1& buffer, const Message& data)
    {
        filler.fill(buffer, data, getMessage());            // V1
        filler.fill<Message>(buffer, data, getMessage());   // V2
    }

private:
    Filler<traceType> filler;
};
```

**The MockClass**

```
template <Class1 traceType>
class MockFiller
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD3(send, void(c1, const Data::SendReq& msg, Class1::StreamInd&));
    MOCK_METHOD3(receive, void(c1, const Data::ReceiveReq& msg, Class1::StreamInd&));

    template <typename Message>
    void fill(c1 buffer, const Message&, Class1::StreamInd& streamInd)
    {
        ASSERT_TRUE(false);
    }
};
```

You can find the explanation of the macro `MOCK_METHODX` in [Google documentation](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/v1_5/CookBook.md).

**Specialization of the MockClass**

```
template <>
template <>
void MockFiller<Class1::TYPE_1>::fill<Data::SendReq>(c1 buffer,
            const Data::SendReq& msg, Class1::StreamInd& streamInd)
{
    send(buffer, msg, streamInd);
}

template <>
template <>
void MockFiller<Class1::TYPE_1>::fill<Data::ReceiveReq>(c1 buffer,
            const Data::ReceiveReq& msg, Class1::StreamInd& streamInd)
{
    receive(buffer, msg, streamInd);
}
```

**Constructor of the MockFiller**

```
class MockFillerConstructor
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(construct, std::shared_ptr<MockFiller<Class1::TYPE_1>>());
};
```

**Class called in the class tested with its macro**

```
#define WRAP_MOCKED_TEMPL_METHOD_1(NAME, TEMPL) \
template <typename TEMPL, typename ...Args>\
auto NAME(Args &&...args)\
{\
    return this->mock().NAME<TEMPL>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);\
}

template <Class1 traceType>
class Filler : public CopyableMockBase<MockFiller<traceType>>
{
public:
    WRAP_MOCKED_TEMPL_METHOD_1(fill, T);
};
```

**So my questions are:**

- why the compiler does not automatically find the template parameter
- why the V2 of my code contains a syntax error

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Google Mock, but your V2 is missing a `template` keyword:

```
filler.template fill<Message>(buffer, data, getMessage());   // V2
```

When `EventLogger` is parsed by the compiler, it does not know what `Filler<traceType>::fill` is supposed to be, and whether the `<` that follows is meant to open a list of template arguments or is simply a less-than operator. Without the `template` keyword, it assumes the latter.

**Edit** Oh wait a minute. For V1, of course it can't deduce `T`. Substituting the macro, you define `Filler<traceType>::fill` like this:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto fill(Args &&...args)
{
    return this->mock().fill<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

(Also note the missing `template` in `this->mock().fill<T>` again here, but that's besides the point really). `T` is not referenced in the function parameter list. How is the compiler going to deduce what it's supposed to be? Why do you even need that `T`? Can't you just do the following?

```
template <typename... Args>
auto fill(Args &&...args)
{
    return this->mock().fill(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```